# Array missing code

Tags: java, arrays

I try to run my code but it always shows me this:

Days of Vacation: 0
Days of Vacation: 0
Days of Vacation: 0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 15 seconds)

```
public class VacationScale {

    int[] vacationDays = new int[7];
    int yearsOfService;

    public void vacationDays() {

        vacationDays = new int[7];
        vacationDays[0] = 10;
        vacationDays[1] = 15;
        vacationDays[2] = 15;
        vacationDays[3] = 15;
        vacationDays[4] = 20;
        vacationDays[5] = 20;
        vacationDays[6] = 25;

    }

    public void displayVacationDays() {
        if (yearsOfService >= 0 && yearsOfService < 6) {

            System.out.println("Days of Vacation: " +
                    vacationDays[yearsOfService]);
        } else if (yearsOfService >= 6) {
            System.out.println("Days of vacation: " + vacationDays[6]);

        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid years of service");
        }
    }

    void setVacationScale() {
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the output do you want to have ?

Comment: `public void vacationDays()` is not a constructor, so it is not called automaticly. Did you call it before calling `displayVacationDays`?

Comment: where is the main method?

Comment: what is this doing? ***setVacationScale*** and why is there if is empty??

Comment: Where is `yearsOfService` ever assigned a value?

Comment: Thanks for sharing Guys.

Answer (score 0):

`public void vacationDays()` is not a constructor but a normal method, so it is not called automaticaly. You probably meant to have it as a constructor.

So replace :

```
  public void vacationDays() {

        vacationDays = new int[7];
        vacationDays[0] = 10;
        vacationDays[1] = 15;
        vacationDays[2] = 15;
        vacationDays[3] = 15;
        vacationDays[4] = 20;
        vacationDays[5] = 20;
        vacationDays[6] = 25;
    }
```

With :

```
public VacationScale() {

    vacationDays = new int[7];
    vacationDays[0] = 10;
    vacationDays[1] = 15;
    vacationDays[2] = 15;
    vacationDays[3] = 15;
    vacationDays[4] = 20;
    vacationDays[5] = 20;
    vacationDays[6] = 25;

}
```

And then `vacationDays` will be initialised when the object is created. And `displayVacationDays` will work as you expect.

Another solution would be to make sure that `vacationDays` is always called at least once before `displayVacationDays` is called.

Your current code work because `vacationDays` is initialised during it's declaration and the default value for an array of int is 0. Which explains the result you currently have.

Comment: Days of Vacation: 20
Days of Vacation: 15
Days of Vacation: 20
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Answer (score -1):

Looks like vacationDays() function is not being called. The code is being run with default values and since int array default value is an array with each element 0 you are getting output as 0

Comment: Thanks Sir for sharing.